# Cosmos DB Set Index Precision

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Get a question related to setting precision using cosmos db sdk .NET v3.
Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-indexing-policy?tabs=dotnetv2%2Cpythonv3#indexing-policy-examples) it says

> This indexing policy is equivalent to the one below which manually sets kind, dataType, and precision to their default values. These properties are no longer necessary to explicitly set and you should omit them from your indexing policy entirely (as shown in above example). **If you try to set these properties, they'll be automatically removed from your indexing policy.**

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/path/to/single/excluded/property/?"
        },
        {
            "path": "/path/to/root/of/multiple/excluded/properties/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does it mean any settings on `precision` will be ignored, or just when `precision = -1`.
Also is there any way to set precision in .NET SDK V3? (I cannot find any api for it)

Comment: The language seems pretty clear about removing the property altogether. If it was just a  `-1` special case, that would be called out. Why do you want to set this?

Comment: @NoahStahl, it could be any number other than -1.

Comment: Given that docs also state "We recommend always setting this value to -1", what are you hoping to achieve by doing otherwise?